# Setting POM version for upload archive in Gradle build

Tags: gradle

I am using Gradle to build my own Android Libraries. I put this libraries into a gradle multi project.

Root Project

Lib A

Lib B

and so on.

I am trying to upload the created aar files into my local maven repo (.m2 directory)

I am using the following commands in my gradle file of the Root Project

```
uploadArchives {
  repositories {
    mavenDeployer {
       repository(url: mavenLocal().url)
        pom.groupId = rootProject.group
        pom.artifactId = project.name
        pom.version = project.version   
    }
  }
}
```

everything works fine except the settings for the project.version. Where can I define the value for every single subproject?

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking out Gradle-Fury at https://github.com/gradle-fury/gradle-fury

Essentially, set the pom.version and various other settings in gradle.properties, add a few `apply from` throughout the build.gradle files and you're set. Definitely works with direct publication to sonatype oss/central.

These settings can be overridden on a per module basis by adding a gradle.properties file in each module that you need to override the parent's settings from.

declaimer: i'm one of the authors